# how to sort int[] in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` with type length 2 `int[]`. `ArrayList<int[]>`
What I want to do is sort the `ArrayList` by increasing order of the second element of `int[1]`.
Is there any built-in method to do this?

Comment: `arrayList.sort((p1, p2) -> p1[1] < p2[1]);`

Comment: Or `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p[1])`.

Comment: I don't understand what p and [1] stand for